# CDT on hover show documentation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

In JDT, if we hover any object, like a function, class, variable etc, eclipse shows the documentation in a tool tip. This documentation is also displayed when the code-assist window shows the possibilities.

However, CDT does not work like this. By default, it shows the code of the hovered object. There's a setting in `Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor -> Hovers`, to choose `Documentation` to be displayed, but unfortunately it does not show anything. Also there's a project called [libhover](http://www.eclipse.org/linuxtools/projectPages/libhover/), but it seems it does not work with in-code doxygen comments.

Is there any solution to mimic JDT hover behavior in CDT?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Eclipse hover tips display Doxygen comments from header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456333/can-eclipse-hover-tips-display-doxygen-comments-from-header-file)

Answer (score 4):

Install LinuxTools plugin to Eclipse C/C++ IDE

```
Help / Install New Software... / Add...
Name=Linux Tools
Location=http://download.eclipse.org/linuxtools/update-3.2
```

[Check for updated LinuxTools location url here](http://www.eclipse.org/linuxtools/downloads.php)

Install following packages, restart Eclipse after it's done.

- C/C++ Library API Documentation Hover Help
- Libhover for Newlib Feature
- Library Hover help for devhelp documentation

You should get tooltips for C standard library functions such as malloc, memset, printf. I just did this for Eclipse Luna (4.2.2) with [MinGW-builds_64bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/) in Windows 7.

I don't know what happens in C++ projects I guess it needs Doxygen tricks which I am not familiar with.